# How do I drop duplicates and keep the last timestamp on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I want to drop duplicates and keep the last  timestamp. The duplicates that want to be dropped is `customer_id` and `var_name` .Here's my data

```
    customer_id  value   var_name     timestamp
    1            1       apple        2018-03-22 00:00:00.000        
    2            3       apple        2018-03-23 08:00:00.000
    2            4       apple        2018-03-24 08:00:00.000
    1            1       orange       2018-03-22 08:00:00.000
    2            3       orange       2018-03-24 08:00:00.000
    2            5       orange       2018-03-23 08:00:00.000
```

So the result will be

```
    customer_id  value   var_name     timestamp
    1            1       apple        2018-03-22 00:00:00.000        
    2            4       apple        2018-03-24 08:00:00.000
    1            1       orange       2018-03-22 08:00:00.000
    2            3       orange       2018-03-24 08:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think need [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.sort_values('timestamp').drop_duplicates(['customer_id','var_name'], keep='last')
print (df)
   customer_id  value var_name                timestamp
0            1      1    apple  2018-03-22 00:00:00.000
3            1      1   orange  2018-03-22 08:00:00.000
2            2      4    apple  2018-03-24 08:00:00.000
4            2      3   orange  2018-03-24 08:00:00.000
```

If dont need sorting - order is important:

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby(['customer_id','var_name'], sort=False)['timestamp'].idxmax()]
print (df)
   customer_id  value var_name           timestamp
0            1      1    apple 2018-03-22 00:00:00
2            2      4    apple 2018-03-24 08:00:00
3            1      1   orange 2018-03-22 08:00:00
4            2      3   orange 2018-03-24 08:00:00
```

Comment: I was not thinking to bed sorted by timestamp :(

Comment: Is that solution 2 is have higher complexity than solution I?

Comment: I think second solution should be a bit slowier.

Comment: In my case, a lot slower