# filter records retain the most recent record in a group

Tags: python, pandas

I would to retain the most recent episodes based on the dates. For example, for **s001** I would to retain the record with **2022-04-05** since it is more recent than the other one

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

record = ['s001', 's002', 's003', 's002', 's004', 's003',
          's004', 's001', 's004', 's003', 's002', 's005']

base = datetime.date.today()
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(len(record))]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": record,
    "date_visited": date_list
})

print(df.sort_values('id'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.sort_values('date_visited').drop_duplicates(['id'], keep='last')
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425727/how-do-i-drop-duplicates-and-keep-the-last-timestamp-on-pandas) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497402/remove-duplicates-by-columns-a-keeping-the-row-with-the-highest-value-in-column)